# how to exactly make a JButton with an image?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, embedded-resource

I'm new to java.

I want to make my image to act as the button in my project. Like the windows phone tile. My frame background is black. And I arranged 6 buttons. I also added an image but it comes with some white spaces around the image as borders. Here is the code i used:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("yellowimage.png");
JButton button = new JButton(image);
```

I dont want those empty spaces. I just want the button to be exactly the image and wanted to type "click me" over the button. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
JButton button = new JButton(image);
button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
button.setBorder(null);
```

You can also change the button image when it is pressed with:

```
button.setPressedIcon(pressedIcon);
```

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you could also use `setBorderPainted`, `setFocusPainted` and `setMargins`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to make JButton with an image.

```
Icon yourIcon = new ImageIcon("yourFile.gif");
JButton button2 = new JButton(yourIcon);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can minimize the border around the image with setMargin();

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("yellowimage.png");
JButton button = new JButton(image);
button.setMargin(new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
JButton button = new JButton();
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(
            ClassName.class.getResource("image.png"));
    button.setIcon(icon);
    button.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    button.setBorderPainted(false);
```